# Jquery apply all events of one element to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I want to apply all the events of "one" to => "two". Events are dynamic with some dynamic ID. Some data is coming on click on one. want to achieve same on click of two (get all events from one)

```
<div class="one">One</div>

<div class="two">two</div>
```

want to achieve something like this:- [Copy events from one element to other using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337521/copy-events-from-one-element-to-other-using-jquery)

but didn't understood it fully. So I made very simple example and wanted to achieve that.

Can we achieve this with Jquery or Javascript?

Comment: What about using `<div class="two" onclick="oneClicked()">two</div>`?

Comment: Are you looking for jquery solution?

Comment: What about triggering the event in jquery like `$('.one, .two').on('click', onClicked())`?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.one,.two').click(function(){
  alert("One");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">One</div>

<div class="two">two</div>
```

use `$('.one,.two')` selector to combine both div

**or**

give same class to all divs

```js
    $('.one').click(function(){
      alert("One");
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="one">One</div>

    <div class="one">two</div>
```

**or**

Call the event manually using `trigger`

`$('.one').trigger('click');.`

Comment: Thanks Sumesh it helped to some extent. But found that I wanted it differently. Updated the question again

Comment: I couldn't understand your requirement completely. You can fire an event programmically like this `$('.one').trigger('click');`.