# How do I check for the existence of a change function?

Tags: jquery, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I find events bound on an element with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008592/can-i-find-events-bound-on-an-element-with-jquery)

I'm using a styled select object to automatically apply styles to all standard select boxes. This is all done in a generic class. In that class, I have a method that needs to trigger the `.change()` event on the select box's parent element, IF a change function is defined. The parent elements are not created in the generic class, and therefore may or may not have a change function explicitly defined.

How can I test to see if there's a change function defined for a specific element (by selector) before calling the trigger?

Comment: Why? You can just trigger the change, even if there isn't any event attached to it.

Comment: Please go ahead and close. The link posted by @ChristianVarga gave me what I needed; I just couldn't seem to get the search terms correct when I was looking for an existing answer.