# How to check if an elem is already listening for a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

When I add an `.on()` event listener twice with the same function, it fires the function twice.
Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/56hxy/13/   (click the 'on' button, then click on the main green div)

How to check if an elem is already listening for a function so as to not add it twice?

```
if (already  $('#id').on('click',functionName)  )
```

Comment: you have this `$('#content').on('click', toggleIt)` twice, one just after the other ... is it planned?

Comment: also maybe interesting to you the [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) binder, like `on` but doesn't allow duplicates

Comment: @JFK yes, only for testing purposes in the fiddle - in a live app I would be adding .on dynamically and need to know if it's already been applied..

Comment: actually one will stop firing the event, and will only fire the repeated click once and after that stop working, and that does not seem to be what he wants, or is it?

Comment: @kieran one() is for one shot only I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unbind the event listner and then add it.

To unbind it use

```
$('#id').unbind('click');
```

Comment: ah, you gave me idea to  $('#id').off('click', functionName)  before turning it on to remove any previous assignment of the same function.  Thanks

Comment: oh wait.. not just different name. I prefer .unbind('click') as you suggested in this case, because it removes all functions assigned to the handler rather than having to turn off individually with .off()

Comment: @bushdiver if you are using `on()` then you could use `off()` instead of `unbind()`

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008592/can-i-find-events-bound-on-an-element-with-jquery) You can use the $._data method, although it's internal so
probably not ideal.

Anyway it would be like: `$._data($("#id")[0], "events")`