# Is there a way to get all default_event_actions, then prevent some except others with event.preventDefault() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, preventdefault

I'd like to know if is there a way to have a list of the default_event_actions for a particular element that '`event.preventDefault()`' has been applied on and tell the script what event or action to prevent or not...

something like:

```
$(element).on('click', function(e){

e.preventDefault() //this will prevent all

//...is there a way of preventing specifically or particularly... 
})
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `e.type` to check type of event and based on condition can prevent default for example:

```
$(element).on('click', function(e){
    if(e.type == 'click')
        e.preventDefault(); //this will prevent all
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Man!...though, What a asking is what are those `defaults` your are preventing... is there a way to list them up?/// thx

Comment: There isn't any list of anything. Prevent Defaults means prevent default action. Means if you click a submit button it's default action is to submit form, so preventDefault prevents that default action attached with the element.

Comment: So you mean each element has a SINGLE SPECIFIC DEFAULT ACTION? are there elements with multiple Default Actions...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery event namespaces to give unique name to your events : [event.namespace](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/)

And to find all events attached to a particular element, you can look at Jonathan Sampson's answer for [this question (Can I find events bound on an element with jQuery?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008592/can-i-find-events-bound-on-an-element-with-jquery)

Comment: Thanx for this, though what a asking is what are those defaults are being prevented when apply `event.prevent()`... is there a way to list them up.. I got this from namespace: `<script>
$( "p" ).on( "test.something", function( event ) {
alert( event.namespace );
});
$( "button" ).click(function( event ) {
$( "p" ).trigger( "test.something" );
});
</script>`