# Decorate jQuery document.ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to decorate jQuery document.ready function

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            console.log("ready2");
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.fn.ready = (function(fn) {
            return function() {
                console.log("ready1");
                return fn.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        })($.fn.ready);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://deelay.me/1000?http://my-site.com/image.gif" />
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm expecting to see - is "ready1" and "ready2" in browser console, however there is only "ready2". What I'm missing?

FiddleJS: http://jsfiddle.net/GXCnu/

UPDATE #1:
Well actually its clear why its not working - its because I'm calling ready() first.... Then another question - how to call custom function just before $.ready() will be triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery just binds to either the `onreadystatechange` or `DOMContentLoaded` events <sup>[[1](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.bindReady)]</sup>.  It checks to see if `document.readyState === "complete"`.

One idea I had was to bind an event to check instead for `this.readyState === 'interactive'`.  This should happen before `"complete"`.

```
$(function () {
    console.log("ready2");
});

$(document).on('readystatechange', function(){
    if(this.readyState === 'interactive'){
        console.log('ready1');
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vP5vZ/

<sup>1</sup> http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.bindReady

Comment: Thank you - its probably the most closely fits my needs. Great solution!

Comment: I don't know if it's the best solution (or if it will work in all browsers), but I'm glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 2):

You call `ready()` first, and only then decorate it. Reverse the order.

Comment: `$.ready` is called immediately and schedules whatever you pass as an argument to be called when the document is ready.

Comment: @Vytalyi: The event is triggered after it's fully processed, yes.  But `$(function() {` is the same as doing `$(document).ready(function(){`, so you are calling `.ready` *before* you modify it.

Comment: yeah... so another question - is there a way how to call my custom function just before $.ready wil be triggered?

Comment: @Vytalyi: Before the event gets triggered?  Why do you want to do that?

Comment: let's say I'm trying to to override some content from my external custom script which is included at the end of <head>. So I need to do it just before DOM ready. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Vytalyi: You can add multiple `$(document).ready` events.  They will be triggered in the order they were set.  Would that work for you?

Comment: the problem is that MY script placed at the end of head - so I don't have a chance/access to modify previously declared $.ready functions.

Comment: @Vytalyi: You can't re-order your scripts?

Comment: No - I can't. My script is ALWAYS at the bottom of head

Comment: @Vytalyi: Then I'm not sure what you can do.  Can you modify the other scripts?

Comment: No its a specific of our product.... The client includes our script at the end of head - we do rest of things. No access to their codebase

Comment: @Vytalyi: I thought of one thing.  The `.ready` event triggers on either the `onreadystatechange` or `DOMContentLoaded` event.  Maybe you can manually bind to that and check `document.readyState` (`.ready` runs when it's "complete").

Comment: Unbind previous events from `ready()` and add your own?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008592/can-i-find-events-bound-on-an-element-with-jquery

Answer (score -1):

This is the fix:

```
$.fn.ready = (function(fn) {
        return function() {
            console.log("ready1");
            return fn.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    })($.fn.ready)();
```

Note the () at the end right before the semicolon.  You must invoke the inner function that gets returned.

Comment: No.  You don't want to invoke the inner function.  You want it to be returned and stored in `$.fn.ready`.