# Check if a event handler is attached to the document

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say i attached an event handler to the document:

```
    $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 38){
           alert("Danger");
        }
    });
```

How can i check now in another function if this event handler is attached to the document. To be more clearer i would like to do something like this:

```
   if($(document).on("keydown"){
       $(document).off("keydown");
   }
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is no harm in trying to remove a listener that is not attached.

Comment: Yes i know my example is not realistic, but if there is no attached keydown i would like to generate a new!

Comment: You'll either have to use the **depreciated** `jQuery._data(element, 'events')` (don't modify this as you're accessing the inernals of jQuery), set your own flag when one is added or assume it's there, remove it and add a new one

Comment: If you goal is to just unbind event, then no need to check anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `$._data`, try this to get all events attached to `document` :

```
$._data($(document)[0], "events")
```

check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008592/can-i-find-events-bound-on-an-element-with-jquery) for more