# Finding all js events associated with a HTML element using Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

Is there a easy way to find all js events that are associated with a specific HTML element using Chrome?

Example:

HTML element

`<a href="#" class="cancel_link refresh_page">Cancel</a>`

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
       $(".cancel_link").click(function () {
          //do something
       });

       $(".refresh_page").click(function () {
          //do something
       });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Right-click element, Inspect Element, in Chrome Developer Tools, in the right pane you will see 'Styles', 'Computed', and '**Event Listeners**'. That lists all events for an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the html element in the `Elements` panel of the dev tools. Then click the `Event Listeners` tab in the right panel. In the top right hand corner of that Event Listeners panel there's a filter icon. When you click on it you can choose "All Nodes" (default) or "Selected Node Only".

Answer (score 2):

- Press F12 to open Developer Tools
- Click the Elements tab
- Select the  element you with to analyze
- On the right hand side click the Event Listeners tab

From that tab you can view all of the handlers bound to the element for each event.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to use jquery, here is a previously posted solution:

```
// Bind up a couple of event handlers
​$("#foo").on({
    click: function(){ alert("Hello") },
    mouseout: function(){ alert("World") }
});​​​

// Lookup events for this particular Element
​$._data( $("#foo")[0], "events" );
```

you can find out more here: [Can I find events bound on an element with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008592/can-i-find-events-bound-on-an-element-with-jquery)