# Get a list of jQuery Events on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to track down a problem in some very complex Javascript and I need to find all the `jQuery(document).ready(` events that are active on the current screen as one of them is causing the problem.

Is there any way from the Javascript console to ask jQuery for the list of ready events set up on the document element? I did some googling and tried:

```
> jQuery(document)
< [#document]

> jQuery(document).data("events")
< undefined
```

Thanks to @ArunPJohny I now have:

```
> jQuery._data(document).events
```

Which returns:

```
Object {mouseup: Array[1], touchstart: Array[2], touchmove: Array[1], touchend: Array[1], click: Array[1]…}
   MSPointerOver: Array[1]
   click: Array[1]
   mousemove: Array[1]
   mouseup: Array[1]
   pointerover: Array[1]
   touchend: Array[1]
   touchmove: Array[1]
   touchstart: Array[2]
   __proto__: Object
```

Comment: `jQuery._data(document).events`

Comment: also see [link .data("events")](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#data-quot-events-quot-)

Comment: `$._data($(document), "events");`

Comment: @BennoZeeman it should be `$._data(document, "events");` - you need to pass a dom element reference no a jQuery object to `$._data()`

Comment: It could be. Doesn't have to be.

Comment: you can test it using SO itself... go to the console and try both of the scripts... `$._data($(document), "events");` returns `undefined` where as `$._data(document, "events");` returns an object

Comment: Ok, I'm making progress thank you @ArunPJohny - one more question, I get the list of events but which of these are the document ready event? I don't see any called that.

Comment: @Arun P Johny Terribly sorry. I even saw it at this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/2008622/2703418 . Sorry.

Comment: @BennoZeeman you'd have to use `get(0)` to do it the way you suggested `$._data($(document).get(0), "events");`

Comment: @andrew Which wouldn't make sense, unless you use a selector to get the JQuery object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I find events bound on an element with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008592/can-i-find-events-bound-on-an-element-with-jquery)