# CefGlue detect evenfint listeners with CefDomVisitor

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, chromium-embedded, cefglue

If I use CEFGlue CefDomVisitor class I can navigate around the DOM. Great, really useful and good job by the developers

Is there any way to pick up what event listeners are associated with a Tag?

Essentially id like to pick up the javascript that 'would' run when the element is clicked (for example). I think I can achieve this by finding out what is listening to the elements event. Then I want to run it independently of the event.

Hope this makes sense, and any help feedback or comment very much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: If you are trying to get information about the DOM and the elements that have events jQuery can help you with that.  But I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: This isn't exactly what you would be looking for but: `$._data( $("#foo")[0], "events" );` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008592/can-i-find-events-bound-on-an-element-with-jquery

Comment: Cap'n the 50 gold coins are in your chest perfect

Comment: Damn how do I mark that as the answer ? I'm i really that dumb!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get information about the DOM and the elements that have events jQuery can help you with that. But I am not sure what you are asking.

This isn't exactly what you would be looking for but: $._data( $("#foo")[0], "events" ); from [event info from jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008592/)