# How to determine what (if) there are jQuery events tied to an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need to determine if a jQuery object has the **jQuery** .`click()` event, if not I need to use the JavaScript one: `$("#Call")[0].click()`

Basically I need a way to this (this is pseudo code):

```
if ($("Call").click() == valid){
    $("Call").click()
} else {
    $("Call")[0].click()
}
```

Comment: Why would you be able to use jquery but not jquery click event?

Comment: `$("#foo").click && $("#foo").click() || $("#foo")[0].click()` however, that makes absolutely no sense. a jQuery object should always have a click property pointing to a function that triggers a click event.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008592/can-i-find-events-bound-on-an-element-with-jquery

Comment: @KevinB I know it doesn't make sense... but it appears as though that is the case

Comment: @KevinB $("#Call").click returns "function (e,n){return arguments.length>0?this.on(t,null,e,n):this.trigger(t)} " but when I call .Click() it doesn't do anything... it doesn't open the page when I .click the link

Comment: click and Click are two different things. was that a typo?

Comment: @KevinB What's the difference?

Comment: `a.b = 5; alert(a.B); // undefined`

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you would need to do it, but to answer your question would mean you need to look up where jQuery stores it's events. if there is an event for that type, there will be an array, if there is no event, than it is undefined.

```
var evtData = $._data($("#Call").get(0)).events;
var hasClickAttached = evtData  && evtData.click !== undefined;
```

Comment: evtData is always null.

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/7dpLe5Ln/ I am not sure why it does not work for you.