# why the trigger click is not working in this case

Tags: jquery

I have a Menu and i am clciking on it using the line

```
  $("#swipecontainer .swiper-slide").eq(centervalue).trigger("click");
```

But i see that never the event listener is getting fired .

This is my code

```
 $(document).on("click", ".swiper-slide", function() {
        alert('i am called');
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/61/

Could you  please let me know how to resolve this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the event before making the call to it.

```
 $(document).on("click", ".swiper-slide", function() {
      alert('i am called');
 });
 $("#swipecontainer").append(favoriteresultag).trigger("create");
 $("#swipecontainer .swiper-slide").eq(centervalue).trigger("click");
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/nx33jez6/**

Comment: dont know that placing of code is also important , thank yiu that resolved my issue .

Comment: @PreethiJain: glad it helps :). you can have a look at this solution to know the event attached to element http://stackoverflow.com/a/2008622/1719752. this way you can verify whether event is attached or not.