# How to find all events inside a container and delegate them

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-delegation

Suppose I have a markup like this

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="abc" onclick="alert(this.innerHTML)">ABC</div>
    <div class="abc1">ABC</div>
    <div class="abc2">abc2</div>
    <div class="xys3">xys3</div>
    <div class="asd23">asd223</div>

</div>
```

And there are events which are bind to the `children` of a `container` like this

```
$( ".abc1" ).bind( "click", function(){
   alert( $( this ).html() );
} );

$( ".abc2" ).bind( "click", function(){
   alert( $( this ).html() );
} );

$( ".xys3" ).bind( "click", function(){
   alert( $( this ).html() );
} );

$( ".asd23" ).bind( "click", function(){
   alert( $( this ).html() );
} );
```

Now, I get the html out of container and set it back again :

```
var html = $( ".container" ).html();
// a set missing here to convert 'bind' events to 'on' events
$( ".container" ).html( html );
```

Events won't work now since they were not delegated to start with. Also, container may be having more elements (they are dynamic).

Is it possible to find all events inside a container and delegate them?

Here is a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/3uorstr7/1/)**

Comment: find events on element  - link (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2008622/5419232) in ur case, u can use $('.container div') or $('.container div').each() depends on ur need.

Comment: @user5419232 after that how do I delegate the event after iterating to it?

Answer (score 4):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the `.bind()` method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements.

So just use event delegation **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** and it will solve the problem :

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".abc2", function(){
    alert( $( this ).html() );
});
```

You could add a general class to all divs then attach click event to it :

**HTML :**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="my-class abc" onclick="alert(this.innerHTML)">ABC</div>
  <div class="my-class abc1">ABC</div>
  <div class="my-class abc2">abc2</div>
  <div class="my-class xys3">xys3</div>
  <div class="my-class asd23">asd223</div>

</div>
```

**JS :**

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".my-class", function(){
     alert( $( this ).html() );
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".my-class", function(){
  alert( $( this ).html() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="my-class abc" onclick="alert(this.innerHTML)">ABC</div>
  <div class="my-class abc1">ABC</div>
  <div class="my-class abc2">abc2</div>
  <div class="my-class xys3">xys3</div>
  <div class="my-class asd23">asd223</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to find out all the events and then iteratively delegate them rather than hard-code it for each class?

Comment: Thanks, but please check the fiddle I had posted. I may not be doing the same thing in all the event handlers. So, needed a way to dynamically iterate, find all the events and then delegating them so that If I simply replace the HTML with the same or different one I shouldn't loose the events. Please give it a go.

Comment: @gurvinder372 see my comment in my answer. That you are thinking is hard and bad practice

Comment: Zak: Not my downvote to anyone (you can have access to mod-tools to verify :)) @MarcosPérezGude I am aware  that is not the best practices. if I had control I would have gone wone with delegation at first place. But I just need to get it done if possible.

Comment: If it is not possible, please share that as well.

Comment: Hey, the downvote is mine! Sorry, I think that I upvoted it. If you edit something in the answer I can fix it

Answer (score 3):

The delegation methods are like this:

```
$(document).on( "click", ".abc1", function(){
     alert( $( this ).html() );
});
```

You can change `$(document)` with an element in the DOM that hasn't change and it's parent of the children you need to delegate. With document will works in every cases, but the performance can be less.

Comment: Is it possible to find out all the events and then iteratively delegate them rather than hard-code it for each class?

Comment: I think that you are thinking in a bad coding. If you need to iterate all html elements, read if there are events attached (all kind of events) and then store them and use it later, maybe your webpage needs a NASA computer to proccess all the javascript you are writing. The delegation method is that I explain here.

Comment: I don't want to use them later, just want to delegate an event as soon as I get one. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I insist: the delegation method is like this.