# Dynamitaclly added HTML in JQUERY class events not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I did this

```
$('div#faq_search_result').replaceWith(decodeHtml(data.html_result));
```

It seems fine but the on click events is not working

this class won't work

```
dt class= "c-faqList__dt"
```

Code for the **JS**

```
var dfd = new $.Deferred();
var self = this;
self.$elm = elm;

self.$elm.on('click','.c-faqList__dt',function(event){
    $(this).siblings('.c-faqList__dd').slideToggle(100)
});

dfd.resolve();
return dfd.promise();
```

Comment: $elm should be on the page before the dynamic content is loaded. It should be a static handle- parent of the loaded content. I believe that's what @epascarello is suggesting.

Comment: it's on a different JS file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
$('div#faq_search_result').parent().on('click','.c-faqList__dt',function(event){
    $(this).siblings('.c-faqList__dd').slideToggle(100)
});
```

assumption: .c-faqList__dt is inside div#faq_search_result

Comment: $('div#faq_search_result').replaceWith(decodeHtml(data.html_result));
this will remove children + events attached on them. If you use event delegation and attach event on parent then events will remain attched.

Comment: yes with $._data. for more:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008592/can-i-find-events-bound-on-an-element-with-jquery