# jQuery delegated event binding not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery 2.2.4. I have three `.note_edit` elements in my page, added dynamically after page load (they are part of CartoDB infowindows).

I am using the following code in the console to check that the elements exist, which they do:

```
$("body .note_edit");
```

Then I am trying to add a dynamic event in the console as follows:

```
$('body').on('click', '.note_edit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); console.log('whatever'); });
```

But when I click on the elements, nothing happens - no console output.

What might be going wrong here? There aren't any other JS errors in the console, the elements definitely exist... what could it be?

[image]

Comment: I'm glad my answer worked for you but I'm still curious as to what was happening exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for other events bound to the elements. [Can I find events bound on an element with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008592/can-i-find-events-bound-on-an-element-with-jquery)

I suspect there is a `e.stopPropagation()` preventing `body` from being reached.