# Javascript - Get events of element and apply to keyboard button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now i am wondering is this below is possible:

I have some element which has some event. Let's say for now that on element click i show `alert('clicked)`;

And the question: is there is any way to grab events of this element and add this events to for example beyboard's left arrow button ?

What i'm looking for is: grab all events from one element and attch this events to another element - in this case it's keyborad button, but this may be for example another DOM element.

Thanks for advice / strategy / info if this is possible.

Edit: i'v found this code snippet, but this don't work, but address well waht i try to do:

```
function copyEvents(source, destination) {
        // Get source events
        var events = source.data('events');

        // Iterate through all event types
        $.each(events, function(eventType, eventArray) {
            // Iterate through every bound handler
            $.each(eventArray, function(index, event) {
                // Take event namespaces into account
                var eventToBind = event.namespace.length > 0
                    ? (event.type + '.' + event.namespace)
                    : (event.type);

                // Bind event
                destination.bind(eventToBind, event.data, event.handler);
            });
        });
    }
    var oldE = $('.old');
    var newE = $('.new');
    copyEvents(oldE, newE);
```

I'm getting this error from jquery.js:
jquery.2.0.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: As I am getting you have to find all events bound with an element by :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008592/can-i-find-events-bound-on-an-element-with-jquery

and can bind them in just simple manner we attach click and other events to elements. You have to use the handler already bounded with that element.

Answer (score 0):

The keypress event builtin to jquery already handles this.

```
var xTriggered = 0;
$( "#target" ).keypress(function( event ) {
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
     event.preventDefault();
  } else if(event.which == event.VK_LEFT){
     event.preventDefault();
     //runfunction();
  }
  xTriggered++;
  var msg = "Handler for .keypress() called " + xTriggered + " time(s).";
  $.print( msg, "html" );
  $.print( event );
});

$( "#other" ).click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).keypress();
});
```

then, just look for which key you want 
link to key event codes:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html