# onclick attribute can't be selected in jquery and not visible in inspector, but working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, magento

I'm working on a magento project with a plugin changes the `onclick` attribute on the `(document).ready()`. I tried to access this attribute using jquery to update it after a user action but it returns `undefined`. And I've noticed that the onclick attribute is NOT visible in the inspector but visible in the page source accessed by `view page source`or`Ctrl + u`.

in inspector the targeted button looks like

```
<button type="button" id="addtocart_btn_5" title="Add to cart" class="button btn-cart btn-cart-with-qty">
    <span>Add to cart<span>
</button>
```

in the page source view it looks like:

```
<button type="button" id="addtocart_btn_5" title="Add to cart" class="button btn-cart btn-cart-with-qty" 
        onclick="setLocation('http://mysite.local/eg_ar/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2hhaXJidXJzdGFyYWJpYS5sb2NhbC9lZ19hci8,/product/5/form_key/lqUtnptjQU7Cn7E1/qty/1/')">
    <span>Add to cart</span>
</button>
```

this button is correctly accessed via the variable `btn` and when i use `console.log(btn.attr("onclick"));` it returns `undefined` but with attribute like `id` it returns the id correctly.

**NOTE**: the button is working very well. but I can't edit it.

**Update**:
as per @Saptal question I've to show more code. in the html part I've this block

```
<div class="add-to-cart">
    <form id="product_addtocart_form_15">
            <span class="custom-counter">
            <input min="1" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="2" value="1" title="qty" class="qty qty-updating" type="number"><div class="custom-counter-nav"><div class="custom-counter-button custom-counter-up">+</div><div class="custom-counter-button custom-counter-down">-</div></div>
        </span>
        <button type="button" id="addtocart_btn_15" title="Add to cart" class="button btn-cart btn-cart-with-qty"><span>Add to cart</span></button>

   </form>

</div>
```

and in js I do that

```
<script>
    jQuery('.qty-updating').each(function(){
        var qty = jQuery(this);

        qty.on('change', function(e){
            alert('here');
            var btn = qty.parent().siblings('.btn-cart');
            console.log(btn.attr("onclick"));
        });

    });
</script>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Show how are you getting `btn`

Comment: @Satpal I've updated the question and added more code

Comment: Try once with `let qty `

Comment: the same result `let qty` & `let qty , let btn` each in separate try

Answer (score 1):

click event is binded to the button and the onclick attribute isn't set explicitly as a html attribute on the button so,

```
btn.attr('onclick')
```

will return **undefined**
and to solve this problem you need to off (unbind) the current click event and on (bind) the new click event as following:

```
btn.off('click');
btn.on('click', function() {
    yourFunction();
});
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: I want to update the url in `onClick` and not to overwrite it. it contains a generated url that can't be regenerated `setLocation('http://mysite.local/sa_ar/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2hhaXJidXJzdGFyYWJpYS5sb2NhbC9zYV9hci8,/product/5/form_key/M3h1IpZ4WmxTNVbX/qty/1/`

Comment: aha .. then you may need to check if you can get the attached click event without the way of accessing the onclick attribute.
please check this question 
[Can I find events bound on an element with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008592/can-i-find-events-bound-on-an-element-with-jquery)

Answer (score -1):

In your issue description you said you use a plugin which changes the onclick attribute. It seems that there is a JS code which actually deletes that attribute. Can you disable that plugin just to make sure the onclick attribute is NOT deleted?

Comment: how it can be deleted ? it's working and visible in the source.

Comment: so you say that the button's onclick event is working even not displaying in inspector??
is it right?? @M.Elwan

Comment: @AbhishekMishra exactly, yes