# how to find number of events bind with html control

Tags: jquery, html, textbox

I have one input and that input have two events bind with it like below

```
<input type="text" class="textinput"/>

<script>
    $(".textinput").focusin(function(){
        //some code
    }
    $(".textinput").focusout(function(){
        //some code
    }
</script>
```

is there any programmatic way to find number of events bind with .textinput" input ?

i tried searching on google but not helping much.

Comment: Why would you need to know the number of attached event handlers?

Comment: increasing my JQuery knowledge :)

Comment: Yes, you can here is the method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008592/can-i-find-events-bound-on-an-element-with-jquery

Comment: you willl get some hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object) and for an actual example [there](https://github.com/ruidfigueiredo/findHandlersJS/blob/master/findEventHandlers.js). But it works only for events registered with jQuery (apparently no way to do this for pure JS events)